# Car starts and goes into gear but doesnt move

Tags: automatic-transmission, lincoln, ls

I have a 06 Lincoln ls now for a while the car wouldn't always accelerate initially hitting the gas but then it would and the car would jerk. Well other day I'm driving and it completely stopped moving while doing about 35. It is an automatic transmission but you can also drive it manual without the clutch. It starts fine goes into gear acts as if its going to move but doesn't in none of the gears but if I switch it to manual it will move I don't even know how to drive manual and it will not reverse. Do you think my transmission is shot?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know for sure, but would suggest your diagnosis of a "shot" transmission is spot on. I'm not sure how the LS transmissions are controlled. I'm not sure if the whole transmission is shot or if the controller for the transmission is toast. Either way you're going to need some professional help on this.

Comment: Check out the transmission control module, also check out see if the flywheel busted and if you can manually turn the crankshaft pulley, inspect inside of the pistons, by taking out the plug and using a flashlight